# Filtro em Java e trabalhando com Servlets

Tags: java, servlet, filter

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou passando por um problema deveras chato, deve ser um pequeno detalhe para resolver o problema e estou perdido em como buscar essa informação que me falta. Bom, chega de choro e segue o relato do problema:

Estou criando um filtro em java com Servlets para capturar todas as requisições que acontecem no contexto /*, ou seja, esse meu filtro será chamado em todas as URLs do meu sistema e, dependendo da URL que o filtro checou, eu vou modificar o HTML da página atual do usuário (digo atual e não a URL em questão porque o filtro passa por todas as requisições, mas eu quero alterar apenas o HTML da primeira requisição, que é a URL que o usuário está acessando).

O primeiro request e response é a própria URL, então a modificação em cima dessa resposta funciona sem problemas, eu pego a resposta em HTML, altero com a informação que quero e depois escrevo dentro dessa resposta

`httpResponse.getOutputStream().write(generateHTML().getBytes())`

O segundo request e response já é outra URL, uma URL que efetua uma operação POST dando como resposta um JSON.

É nesse segundo request e response que estou quebrando a cabeça. Como a resposta desse cara é um JSON, não consigo manipular esse cara e jogar para o usuário um novo corpo de html dentro do html da URL atual.

Pensei em algo como guardar a resposta do primeiro filtro realizado, para assim quando a URL que eu procuro passar pelo filtro, eu conseguir alterar a resposta somente do filtro que já foi feito no início, mas sem sucesso... :/

Alguma dica? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Por que você está usando servlets? Imagino que seja com propósito acadêmico, pois ele é não é ideal para tratar o redirecionamento de páginas de um sistema e a escrita dos seus dados (por isso a sua dificuldade para resolver o problema de forma elegante). Para isso, é interessante utilizar um framework, como JSF, por exemplo.

Comment: Não posso fugir do Servlet, porque estou criando um plugin em cima do JIRA que todo o seu ambiente foi feito em cima dessa tecnologia. O meu sistema é só um add-on para um sistema maior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, resolvi esse problema de outra forma.

Ao invés criar um novo html dentro da resposta do usuário, eu só o direciono para a minha página que contém o HTML. Assim fica mais fácil de trabalhar com todos os tipos de requisições.